# Bootable Linuxmint on USB not working

Tags: operating-system, usb, linux-mint, bootable

I am trying to install linuxmint on my new hard drive but every time I try to boot it from my USB I only get 'Reboot and Select proper Boot device' in my monitor. I tried booting the USB on my laptop and it worked but not in my PC.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to try:

1) different USB slot on the target machine

2) different USB stick

3) checking the stick's access settings

4) different version of Mint